# Has the Gaussian Process the Markov Property only when is variance is a diagonal matrix?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I'm studying stochastic process and Markov Chain.

I was wondering if a Gaussian Process has the Markov Property (that is the conditional probability distribution (given the present states) of future states is independent of the past states). 
Personally, following my intuition, I would say that a Gaussian Process has the Markov Property only when the covariance of the Gaussian is a diagonal matrix.

My reasoning is the following: A Gaussian Process with a diagonal covariance matrix is a process of independently distributed random variables, and so by definition has the Markov Property.

Is my reasoning correct? Is the assumption of diagonal covariance necessary?

Comment: An [Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process) is described as a non-trivial stationary Gauss–Markov process

Comment: Thank you for the resource, but it's really hard to understand if my reasoning is correct from that Wikipedia page

Comment: I believe that [a section of the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process#Formulas_for_moments_of_nonstationary_processes) points to the covariance matrix being non-diagonal, even if you adjust the calculation to $\text{cov}(x_s,x_t-x_s)$ with $t \gt s$, something which would be $0$ with a Wiener process